# Todays date as column name

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql, select, dynamic-sql

Im trying to get the state field in the below query to have today's date as the column alias:

```
SELECT      
    State,
    GroupNumber,
    FacilityNumber,
    CASE WHEN Pyes IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE Pyes END  AS PCY,
    CASE WHEN Pno IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE Pno END AS PCN,
    CASE WHEN CYes IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE CYes END AS CTY,
    CASE WHEN CNo IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE CNo END AS CTN,
    CASE WHEN Appointed IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE Appointed END AS Appointed,
    CASE WHEN Super IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE Super END AS Super,
    CASE WHEN NFR IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE NFR END AS NFR,
    CASE WHEN RN IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE RN END AS RN,
    CASE WHEN Speech IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE Speech END AS Speech,
    CASE WHEN Occupation IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE Occupation END AS Occupation,
    CASE WHEN Physio IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE Physio END AS Physio,
    CASE WHEN EN IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE EN END AS EN,
    CASE WHEN Diet IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE Diet END AS Diet,
    CASE WHEN MD IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE MD END AS MD,
    CASE WHEN HW IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE HW END AS HW,
    CASE WHEN Cleaner IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE Cleaner END AS Cleaner,
    CASE WHEN Cook IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE Cook END AS Cook,
    CASE WHEN CSW IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE CSW END AS CSW,
    CASE WHEN GA IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE GA END AS GA,
    CASE WHEN [Tel/Chat] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE [Tel/Chat] END AS 'Tel/Chat',
    CASE WHEN FPH IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE FPH END AS FPH
FROM DTE
ORDER BY CASE
WHEN State = 'ACT' THEN '1'
WHEN State = 'NSW' THEN '2'
WHEN State = 'NT' THEN '3'
WHEN State = 'QLD' THEN '4'
WHEN State = 'VIC' THEN '5'
WHEN State = 'SA' THEN '6'
WHEN State = 'WA' THEN '7'
WHEN State = 'TAS' THEN '8'
WHEN State = 'NULL' THEN '9'
END
```

I have tried to use a dynamic SQL statement for the above but the data is coming from a nested CTE statement and throws the error `Invalid object name 'DTE'`:

```
DECLARE @dt NVARCHAR(50) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
SELECT      
    State AS ''' + @dt + ''',
    CASE WHEN Pyes IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE Pyes END  AS PCY,
    CASE WHEN Pno IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE Pno END AS PCN,
    CASE WHEN CYes IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE CYes END AS CTY,
    CASE WHEN CNo IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE CNo END AS CTN,
    CASE WHEN Appointed IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE Appointed END AS Appointed,
    CASE WHEN Super IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE Super END AS Super,
    CASE WHEN NFR IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE NFR END AS NFR,
    CASE WHEN RN IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE RN END AS RN,
    CASE WHEN Speech IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE Speech END AS Speech,
    CASE WHEN Occupation IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE Occupation END AS Occupation,
    CASE WHEN Physio IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE Physio END AS Physio,
    CASE WHEN EN IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE EN END AS EN,
    CASE WHEN Diet IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE Diet END AS Diet,
    CASE WHEN MD IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE MD END AS MD,
    CASE WHEN HW IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE HW END AS HW,
    CASE WHEN Cleaner IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE Cleaner END AS Cleaner,
    CASE WHEN Cook IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE Cook END AS Cook,
    CASE WHEN CSW IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE CSW END AS CSW,
    CASE WHEN GA IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE GA END AS GA,
    CASE WHEN [Tel/Chat] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE [Tel/Chat] END AS ''Tel/Chat'',
    CASE WHEN FPH IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE FPH END AS FPH
FROM DTE
ORDER BY CASE
WHEN State = ''ACT'' THEN ''1''
WHEN State = ''NSW'' THEN ''2''
WHEN State = ''NT'' THEN ''3''
WHEN State = ''QLD'' THEN ''4''
WHEN State = ''SA'' THEN ''5''
WHEN State = ''WA'' THEN ''6''
WHEN State = ''TAS'' THEN ''7''
WHEN State = ''NULL'' THEN ''8''
END'
```

Im also unable to put the entire query into a dynamic SQL query as the query exceeds 4000 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could largely shorten the query by using `ISNULL()` instead of these multiple `CASE` expressions. As an example, this:

```
CASE WHEN Pyes IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE Pyes END  AS PCY
```

Can be rewritten into the shorter:

```
ISNULL(Pyes, 0) as PCY
```

You could also shorten the `ORDER BY` clause a little, by avoiding repeating the column name:

```
ORDER BY CASE State
    WHEN 'ACT' THEN 1
    WHEN 'NSW' THEN 2
    WHEN 'NT'  THEN 3
    ...
    ELSE 8
END
```

This should be enough to decrease the size of your statement under 4000 chars.

*If* that still too long, then a typical trick is to split the query into smaller text chunks (each of them having less than 4000 chars). You can then use the `+` operator to concatenate them into a string, that would magically be allowed to be longer than 4000 chars.

Side notes:

- don't use single quotes for identifiers - they are meant for literal strings. instead, use the relevant quoting character for your database (in SQL Server, use square brackets). So this: `State AS ''' + @dt + '''` should be written `State AS [' + @dt + ']`
- the `ORDER BY` clause should use numbers rather than strings - otherwise, if you have 10 values or more, you will have discrepencies in the sort, due to string sorting rules (string wise, `'10'` is smaller than `'2'`).
- the last `CASE` branch does not look right: this is checking the string against *literal string* `'NULL'`, which is probably not what you want (better yet, use `ELSE`, as shown above)

Comment: Congrats on 100K +1.  Sadly, SO no longer gives out swagger packages for 100K and 250K.  I got one for 100K several years ago, but just missed the 250K package.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: thank you, much appreciated! I didn't even know that these packages existed.... Guess that there are just too many +100k users now!

Comment: Yeah points here are like sky miles, they have become diluted over the years.

Comment: Congrat @GMB! Good job.

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot, the final case statement is just so i can have null states ordered at the bottom of the returned my DTE query has this line `SELECT 'NULL' AS State` this is for when the state isn't recognised as one of the 7 Australian states and territories.

Comment: Not "IFNULL" but "ISNULL"